# Grails, Groovy - tokenize() splitting a comma and whitespace together

Tags: regex, grails, groovy, tokenize

I have a Grails project that gets list of input from a form.
I used an autocomplete jQuery UI and lists `courses` like `English, Math, Science, Social Studies,`. When I use the `tokenize(', ')` method, it splits `Social Studies`. The list becomes `[English, Math, Science, Social, Studies]` If I use `tokenize(',')` it does not split `Social Studies` but puts `null` at the end like `[English, Math, Science, Social Studies, null]`

```
def save(Student studentInstance) {
....
    def courseInputList = params.course.tokenize(', ')
        for (item in courseInputList){  
            def courseID = Course.findByCourseLike(item)
            StudnetCourse.link(studentInstance,courseID)
        }
....
}
```

How can I have the `tokenize()` delimeter be exactly `,(one whitespace)`, but either `,` or `(one whitespace)`.
I hope what I'm trying to explain makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

(I have it, for now, that javascript doesn't put a whitespace after a comma. It works fine with one delimeter. )

Comment: Is the trailing comma after `Social Studies,` really necessary? That's the reason you're getting an additional `null` when using `','` to tokenize.

Comment: javascript puts `,(one space)` after each autocomplete. This is the source I used. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use split instead

```
params.course = params.course?.split(', ')?: []

params.course.each{ item ->
        def courseID = Course.findByCourseLike(item)
        StudnetCourse.link(studentInstance,courseID)
}
```

Comment: I tried. When the field is empty (the field is not required) it keeps an empty list and throws errors.

Comment: Yes, it works.  Thanks. So `?` is for only when there is a value, right?
What about `: [ ]`? Is the statement putting the list in an array only when there is a value?

Comment: The elvis operator ?: assigns the value from the left to the variable (when the condicion is true). If that condition is not true , I create an empty list, because after that, I call to an each collection function. I prevent the situation when params.course is null, so if the params  is null, the each does not fail, and there is no iteration

Comment: The ? comand is converting each time you calling the parameter into a boolean (using groovy truth). params.course?.split()? is checking if params.course exists and split does not give a null or empty list. So if all of this returns a list, I append it to the params.course.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have no control over the String input, which gets a trailing comma at the end, I suggest you do some processing of the input first before tokenization or splitting.

Assuming your input string is `input`,

```
def input = params.course
```

you can either use slicing,

```
def processedString = input.endsWith(',') ? input[0..input.size() - 1] : input
```

or string subtraction using regular expression,

```
def processedString = input - ~/,\s*$/
```

which will remove the trailing comma. The only difference is that, with the string subtraction, the regex also checks for any trailing white spaces after the comma so it's a lot more flexible.

With the trailing comma gone, you can do tokenization or splitting. I suggest you use `','` to do so and just `trim` in the resulting list of outputs to remove the spaces.

```
def courses = processedString.split(',').collect { it.trim() }
```

So the resulting code would be:

```
def processedString = params.course - ~/,\s*$/
def courses = processedString.split(',').collect { it.trim() }
courses.each { course ->
    //do what you want to do with course
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the concept I was thinking of but didn't know the correct syntax. I'm learning a lot today.

Comment: To find out more about regular expression patterns in Groovy (Java), check out the [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).